# Line across page based on content length

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have googled a lot of things that I thought could yield an answer to my question, but here I am, asking for your help once again.

I'm using React and React-Bootstrap.

I would like to have a vertical line along my page as long as content goes (exactly like a timeline).
Currently what I do is:

```html
<div className="timeline">
....Content
</div>
```

and the css:

```css
.timeline:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
```

I think what's happening is that the line gets drawn first before React renders content, so the 100% will be smaller than the actual 100%.
I would like this line to expand based on content length, preferably dynamically.

I thought of creating a react component, and draw the line once every other component is mounted, but I think there is a better way to solve this and I'm not sure if that would work.

I'm also adding a screenshot here so that you will see the problem:
[line ending but content is going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmx1s.png)

Comment: Can you share the HTML too? You can also use tools like jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: I will create a fiddle asap

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I was unsuccesful in creating a fiddle replicating the exact same problem, because the fiddle would always just draw it top to bottom, but in the end I attached a line to the content elements, that together make it a continuous line. It's a bit of a hack but that's how I solved it.